# Is there anyway to make Objects on C# chart to be clickable and return index of the object ?

Tags: c#, plot, charts

I am new to C# programming, while i am working on graphs, is there anyway to make the objects(plotted points in the chart to be clickable, and when they are clicked they should return the index of the object ?

[image]

This is the picture of the chart that i am working on. Any help will be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# mouse click events on datapoints in a chart](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10784628/c-sharp-mouse-click-events-on-datapoints-in-a-chart)

Comment: Visual Studio doesn't come with a chart UI component so I'm assuming that you're using a third party. You need to let us know the provider of the component otherwise no one will be able to help you

Comment: i am simply using this System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting